# Unrecognized variable in if statement

Tags: c

I have a little problem with my program. In my IF statement my variable is not being recognized.

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++){
    printf("%d:", i);

        for(j=0;pom[j]!='\0';j++){
                if(pom[j]==X) star++;
        }
    X++;
    printf("%d", star);
    printf("\n");
    star=0;
}
```

Variable X is defined as `int X=0;` in this function. It is supposed to be a number from 1 - 9 but its not changing its value throught the code even if I have `X++;` right after my for loop.

This code runs great when I remake it to `if(pom[j]=='1') star++;` or `if(pom[j]=='2') star++;` or whatever number from my desired interval, so I think the problem is in my if statement syntax. Any ideas guys? Thank you for your help.

Comment: you're probably confused about the type.. int != char

Comment: @duedl0r char is an integral type :-)

Comment: @Aniket I think duedl0r means e.g. `1` != `'1'`.

Comment: @Aniket: then you know that 1 != '1' :)

Comment: I am still thinking what OP is trying to achieve, a bunch of code and some weird explanation -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your *if* statement you are comparing a *char* (I am supposing that pom is a char) with an *int*.The ASCII code of '1' is the integer numer 49, and not 1. You can do:

```
if (pom[j] == (x + 48))
```

An alternative way is to declare:

```
char X = '0';
```

Read the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: I don't know what OP is trying to achieve, and what `pom[]` is

Comment: @Dukeling I think that if you use X as integer, is more readable `x + 48`. Some beginner can be confused and thinking to a string concatenation. The integer expression is more explicit. But it is just my opinion :)

Comment: One of the first things you should learn in C is that `+` is not string concatenation. If starting from C, you should learn this long before you memorize the ASCII table (who's memorized the ASCII table?) (although `'0'` is probably the most useful value to know). But, yes, I suppose it's all just opinions.

Comment: @Dukeling you are right but, unfortunately, I met  "experienced" programmer who does not know how to use correctly *for loop* and *array*. So, I personally prefer to avoid any kind of mistake or misunderstanding :)